# Как синхронизировать несколько запросов?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Как синхронизировать несколько запросов?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Я недавно в JavaScript, и если вызываю несколько запросов, то работает только один.

Comment: Приведите пример кода который у вас не получается синхрогизировать

Comment: @андрей приведи в вопросе пример твоих нескольких запросов?

Comment: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap"
                async defer></script>

Comment: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBi1Y1cWqNrCrI8oqgn0Ue4aeFi4NqQRVA&callback=initMap"
                async defer></script>

Comment: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBi1Y1cWqNrCrI8oqgn0Ue4aeFi4NqQRVA&callback=initMap"
                async defer></script> инициализирует карту <script
               
               src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBi1Y1cWqNrCrI8oqgn0Ue4aeFi4NqQRVA&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
               
        async defer></script> автозаполнение форм и работает только одно из них

Answer (score 0):

Потому что это JSONP и все данные отправляются одной и той же функции `initMap`, указанной в параметре `callback=initMap`. К тому же, нет смысла запрашивать один и тот же скрипт карт несколько раз. Вероятно, на самом деле требуется что-то другое.