# Не работают несколько запросов javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

На одной страничке располагаются функции инициализации карт от гугл и функция автозаполнения форм тоже от гугла, и они никак не хотят работать вместе:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Тут вызывается автозаполнение:

```
<script
     src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>
```

В итоге работает или карта или автозаполнение полей, но вместе ну никак не хотят. В чем может быть причина? Я недавно работаю с javascript и многого не знаю.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [не работают несколько запросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681852/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Не нужно повторно создавать вопрос. Если требуется добавить какую-то информацию в вопрос, это можно сделать с помощью кнопки "Править" в нижней части вопроса.

Comment: а вы `API_KEY` заменили на ключ который вам выдал гугл?